# Laravel Sail Docker Hub

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerhub, laravel-sail

I've got laravel sail which as I know is few containers (mysql, redis, laravel, ...). Is there an easy way to just pack up the whole thing to ex. Docker Hub and easly download it on production server, and when i update it on localhost and run `docker push`, just run `docker pull`. Then everything (like new commands in DockerFile | `apt install thing`) will be updated and working exacly how it worked on localhost

I read the documentation, but I cannot figure out how docker works and how to easly change project location (Ex. I'm working on project at work, sometimes at home and this will be much easier to run `docker push` when I need build source code and deploy it)

I'm keeping source code on github, and it's working for dev servers, but to deploy something I have to check all dependencies and DockerFile, .env file and other things to make it works on production.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing docker-compose.yml and just run `docker-compose up -d` on production to start all containers. Just be sure to for example disable xdebug on production as it slows down every request.